# mysql_fetch_assoc returning NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with the following script which is suppose the next increment value

---

```
$lastidquery = "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE( ) AND TABLE_NAME = 'user';";

$lastid = mysql_query($lastidquery);

$id = mysql_fetch_assoc($lastid);

$next_increment = $id['Auto_increment'];
```

---

The `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns a `null` while the mysql_query returns = `resource(9, mysql result)`

Comment: But why the blazes are you trying to get the last/next autoincrement id this way? It will cripple any application that you write to a single concurrent request, unless you want to cause problems on your database

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. Just don't. They are deprecated and if you are developing something today then don't depend on obsolete aspects of the language. Besides, they are insecure (which is the reason they are deprecated.)

Comment: It might help to explain what you are trying to do rather than just asking us to debug the code. As @MarkBaker mentioned, this is not even close to standard practice...

Comment: And `'Auto_increment' !== 'AUTO_INCREMENT'`

Comment: What does mysql_error() have to say?

Comment: I am trying to get the next increment value that I need to use as a foreign key in another table when adding a new row.

Comment: Doesn't Mysql have LAST_INSERT_ID() for this? Granted, it returns the last inserted id (as its name says), but if you need the value as a foreign key in another table, common sense indicates that you should insert the values in the main table first, and then insert them in the foreign key table.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to PaulJ.

I was trying to get the next increment value that I need to use as a foreign key in another table when adding a new row.

I actually inserted the data for the parent table, got the last inserted key using **$last_id = $connect->insert_id;** and then inserted the data in the child table using the obtained id as foreign key.